# filtering non empty or undefined object value

Tags: javascript, lodash

Trying to filter out undefined object values.

```
const activeCard = _.pickBy(cards);
```

console output of activeCard shows the below object.

```
 { cardValue1: 
   [ { account_value: '4422444443333004',
       country: 'US',
       month: '01',
       year: '2029',
       confirmation: [Object] } ],
  cardValue2: [ { account_value: undefined } ],
  cardValue3: [ { account_value: undefined } ] }
```

I tried something like this which didnt work

```
const newObject = _.omitBy(activeCard, _.isNil);

// also tried to filter out at the level of _.pickBy which didnt work

const activeCard = _.pickBy(cards, (value) => { return value.length > 0; });

// output i am looking for is something like below
[ { account_value: '4422444443333004',
       country: 'US',
       month: '01',
       year: '2029',
       confirmation: [Object] } ]
// So basically, Im looking for output with 'undefined' object values filtered out.
```

Answer (score 0):

use a custome function maybe?

```
function sanitize(a) {
  let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
  for (const key in b) {
    if (Array.isArray(b[key])) {
      if (_.isEmpty(b[key][0])) delete b[key]
    }
  }
  return b;
}
const filteredActiveCard = sanitize(activeCard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.filter()` and check with `Array.some()` (or lodash `_.some()`) if the property's array contains an `account_value` which is not `nil`. Then flatten the results to a single array.

```js
const activeCard = {"cardValue1":[{"account_value":"4422444443333004","country":"US","month":"01","year":"2029","confirmation":[null]}],"cardValue2":[{}],"cardValue3":[{}]}

const result = _.flatten(_.filter(activeCard, arr => 
  arr.some(o => !_.isNil(o.account_value))
))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

With lodash/fp you can create a function that filters by iterating with `_.some()`, getting the `account_value`, and checking if it's not `nil`. Then flattens the results to a single array.

```js
const { filter, some, flow, get, negate, isNil, flatten } = _

const fn = flow(
  filter(some(flow(
    get('account_value'),
    negate(isNil)
  ))),
  flatten
)

const activeCard = {"cardValue1":[{"account_value":"4422444443333004","country":"US","month":"01","year":"2029","confirmation":[null]}],"cardValue2":[{}],"cardValue3":[{}]}

const result = fn(activeCard)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash makes this super easy.

```js
const cards = {
 cardValue1: 
   [ { account_value: '4422444443333004',
       country: 'US',
       month: '01',
       year: '2029',
       confirmation: [Object] } ],
  cardValue2: [ { account_value: undefined } ],
  cardValue3: [ { account_value: undefined } ] 
 }

const activeCards = _(cards)
      .pickBy(v => v.length)
      .values()
      .flatten()
      .filter('account_value')
      
console.log(activeCards);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```